# Android: Design consideration for layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have to design the following layout:[image: Planner], which basically resembles a planner. Here, I have to show schedule for whole week. So far, I had completed the following part [image: completed].

---

Now, I am stuck with this part: [image: incomplete]. I am not getting idea to design this part.
The highlighted portion in the grid indicates an event at that time. My problem is how can I make grids the one illustrated.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [2D graphics](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html) and draw it completely in code.
It will be really hard to use xml to achieve this design, You could give it a shot with AbsoluteLayout but it is deprecated.

As about algorithm how to do it, first define a range of hours Your timetable will have,
You don't need full 24h, if all events are in range 8am-8pm for example displaying hours from 8pm to 8am would be a waste of sapce.
Get size of screen and calculate a size of one rectangle for the smallest time-frame.
And later it is simple maths to calculate position and size of rectangle to represent event.

Comment: Can you please, provide some demo or tutorial link, as I am not very familiar with Canvas.

Comment: I don't keep link to tutorials in my bookmarks but here You have something I found quickly and looks simple to start with [Canvas for beginners](http://danielnadeau.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/android-canvas-beginners-tutorial.html) for more just google "Android canvas drawing tutorials"

Comment: This is the best approach.  Google "Canvas" and "SurfaceHolder", I think those are the two classes you need to get started.  This will perform exponentially better than it would with XML.